# Behave in python using or in .feature fles

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, python-behave

I need Behave to pass full scenario even when at least 1 element is correct and fail when none of them were found.

For example, I have tried something like this but it returns error for elements that were not found and only true for elements it did found.

```
Scenario Outline: Elements
   When Screen loads
   Then Element "<element>" is visible

 Examples: Consumer Electronics
   | element       |
   | 1             |
   | 2             |
   | 3             |

# or this:

Scenario: Elements
   When Screen loads
   Then Element "1" or "2" or "3" is visible
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found workaround that allowed me to make check for 1 or more elements in Behave and reuse it in later steps. Good thing it doesn't break our codebase as it still works if only one element is checked.

```
Scenario: Elements
    When Screen loads
    Then Element "1 or 2 or 3" is visible

@then('Then Element "{element}" is visible')
    def step_impl(context, element):
        posible_elements = element.split(' or ')
        for elem in posible_element:
            # make check for each elem
            # or save visible element to context.visible_element
```

Answer (score 1):

**1. First, You cannot use scenario outline in this situation.**
Scenario outline actually will split into scenarios, if in examples you have 3 rows (1,2,3) then there are 3 scenarios will be run And each scenario only verify 1 Element.

**2. Behave (Gerkin) does not have anything like "OR". you have to do what you want in step definition.**

your second scenario can be used:

Scenario: Elements
When Screen loads
Then Element "1" or "2" or "3" is visible

```
@then('Element "{element1}" or "{element2}" or "{element3}" is visible')
def step_assert_element(context, element1, element2, element3):
    elm1 = Page(context.driver).is_element_visible(elm1_locator)
    elm2 = Page(context.driver).is_element_visible(elm2_locator)
    elm3 = Page(context.driver).is_element_visible(elm3_locator)
    assert_that(elm1 or elm2 or elm3, equal_to(True), "Verify One of Element is visible")
```